# Client IP Address in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I need to obtain client local IP address into internal network not the IP over internet by angular for some reason that data will send to IP address over network not based on authorization,I googled so much and I can just find the IP over internet,
Now how can I solve this issue? thanks

Comment: You can't do that. If you could, that would de-anonymise everybody who uses a VPN, or TOR or a proxy.

Answer (score 0):

Client IP address cannot be accessible by you or with any NPM from front end.

U can find different IP's over internet don't use it.

If you want the client IP, can only be accessed in Node.js.

***NPM - request-ip***